# Existence of Pseudorandom Generator

Tags: randomized-algorithms, pseudo-random-generators

How to show that for $\epsilon>0$, there exists a function $G:\{0,1\}^n->\{0,1\}^{2^{\epsilon n}}$ that is a $2^{\epsilon n}$-prg, without the condition that is is computable in $2^{O(n)}$ time. What I am trying to show is with high probability, if we take $\epsilon=1/10$, a random $G$ satisfies this condition. But in order to show that, we need to show, no circuits of size $<2^{3/10n}$ are able to distinguish between uniform distribution of length $2^{n/10}$ and output of $G$. This I am not able to get. Can anyone give me an approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you choose $G$ from the uniform random distribution on $\{0, 1\}^n \to \{0, 1\}^{2^{\epsilon n}}$ without restrictions, then nothing can (correctly) distinguish between the uniform distribution and the output of $G$, because you made it uniformly random by definition. At this point the output of $G$ is no longer pseudo-random, it *is* random.

Comment: But how to prove the statement in terms of the definition of pseudorandom generators? Also how to use $\epsilon=1/10$? The question is given in arora barrak Computational Complexity, chapt 16 ex-2

Comment: @DiptajitRoy I'm sorry, I don't know. Your approach where you choose $G$ to be random doesn't work though, no matter what, due to the reason in my answer, I'm assuming that wasn't part of the original question.